# C++ variable addresses & alignment | x86

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, alignment

I have the following code in VS2010:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a = 5;
    char b = 'c';
    int c = 7;
    char e = 'y';
    return 0;
 }
```

And this is what the disassembly looks like:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

00E01380 55                   push        ebp  
00E01381 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
00E01383 81 EC 00 01 00 00    sub         esp,100h  
00E01389 53                   push        ebx  
00E0138A 56                   push        esi  
00E0138B 57                   push        edi  
00E0138C 8D BD 00 FF FF FF    lea         edi,[ebp-100h]  
00E01392 B9 40 00 00 00       mov         ecx,40h  
00E01397 B8 CC CC CC CC       mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00E0139C F3 AB                rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
    int a = 5;
*00E0139E* C7 45 F8 05 00 00 00 mov         dword ptr [a],5  
    char b = 'c';
*00E013A5* C6 45 EF 63          mov         byte ptr [b],63h  
    int c = 7;
*00E013A9* C7 45 E0 07 00 00 00 mov         dword ptr [c],7  
    char e = 'y';
*00E013B0* C6 45 DB 79          mov         byte ptr [e],79h  
    return 0;
00E013B4 33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
}
```

I am working on a 64 bit system. When I look at the addresses, I do not understand how they are aligned. I expected that they would be 8 byte aligned. 
See below:

```
00E0139E   - here starts int a, 4 byte integer
      9F   - int a
      A0   - int a
      A1   - int a
      A2   - padding
      A3   - padding
      A4   - padding
      A5 - char b, 1 byte
-end of word
      A6 - padding???
      A7 - padding???
      A8 - padding???
      A9 - here starts int c, why?
      AA - int c
      AB - int c
      AC - int c
      AD - padding???
-end of word
      AE - padding???
      AF - padding???
      B0 - char e, why?
```

This is really confusing for me.
Could someone help me understand what is going on?
This doesn't seems like an effective way to store variables. It must be that I've missed something.

PS: optimization is disabled in the project options. I also tried

```
#pragma runtime_checks( "su", off )
```

but it didn't change anything.

Comment: You are looking at code addresses, ie. where the instructions are, not where the data is in memory. The addresses are what they are because instructions take variable number of bytes, and that's just how many these particular ones need.

Comment: You may be working on a 64-bit system, but you showed 32-bit asm code.  (Either 32-bit and 64-bit code can be used on a 64-bit OS).  So don't expect 4-byte integers to be 8 byte aligned.  For your actual question, as Jester said, you seem to be confusing the code locations with the data locations.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at code addresses, ie. where the instructions are, not where the data is in memory. The addresses are what they are because instructions take variable number of bytes, and that's just how many these particular ones need.

That said, if you look at the actual disassembly you can see that the variables are not packed efficiently. However, with optimizations disabled, that's not unexpected. For starters, you can see that the compiler allocated a whopping 256 bytes for your locals using `sub esp,100h`. Then the variables are assigned like:

```
c745f805000000 mov DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x5
c645ef63       mov BYTE PTR [ebp-0x11],0x63
c745e007000000 mov DWORD PTR [ebp-0x20],0x7
c645db79       mov BYTE PTR [ebp-0x25],0x79
```